# Memcache results and while loop

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I wrote this function for caching queries:

```
function get_cached($query, $type = 1) {

  $key = md5(strtolower($query));
  $cached = $memcache->get($key);

  if($cached) {
      $res = unserialize($cached);
  } else {
    $r =  mysql_query($query);

      if($mode == 1) {
            $res = mysql_fetch_object($r);  
         } else {
            $res = mysql_fetch_array($r);
         }
     $memcache->store($key, serialize($res));
  }

  return $res;

}
```

And it kinda works, i can cache simple queries. But i have problem with queries that operate within loops.
I really can't understand how to get around this, and "port" this  to use my get_cached() function first.

```
$ref = mysql_query("query");

while($res = mysql_fetch_object($ref)) {

     //do something with results

}
```

How i can do it through cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store the mysql result object but you can fetch all rows into an array and cache the array. like

```
function get_cached($query, $type = 1) {

  $key = md5(strtolower($query) . $type);
  $cached = $memcache->get($key);

  if($cached) {
      return unserialize($cached);
  } else {
        $r =  mysql_query($query);
        $data = array();

        if($mode == 1) {
            foreach($row = mysql_fetch_object($r)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            foreach($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }

        $memcache->store($key, serialize($data));
  }

  return $data;
}
```

don't forget to store the `type` of your functions as cache key too, otherwise you fetch a results set with `type==1` and in return you get the elements as `array`